# Need help getting a shift to return a time frame in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to get a formula into excel that will return a time frame based on the Shift entered in a cell. I see a lot of questions doing the opposite, taking a time frame and returning Shift 1, Shift 2 or Shift 3, but I can't seem to work the formulas backwards to fit what I'm working towards.

For reference the Shift Column, if
1 should return 6:45 am to 2:45 pm
2 should return 2:45 pm to 10:45 pm
3 should return 10:45 pm to 6:45 am

Excel Shift Snippet

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

- Use the `INDEX` function: store the 3 shift timeframes in range `Q3:Q5` and find the correct time from it.  Here is what it gives: [screenshot_solution_formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCRiu.png) (I've added two more columns for start and end in case it helps, but no problem if we remove them). Below is the formula to put in L2 and to pull.

```
L2 = INDEX(Q$3:Q$5,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($K2,1)),0)
```

- Use the `CHOOSE function` to choose from different timeframes specified in formula, by putting this in L2:

```
L2 = CHOOSE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($K2,1)),"6:45 am to 2:45 pm"," 2:45 pm to 10:45 pm", "10:45 pm to 6:45 am")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can't tell you how much I appreciate it. I ended up using the choose function and it works perfectly.